# Not getting returned value from async await function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am getting undefined returned value when I press button.

```
<Button btnType="outline" onClick={LockUnlockAccountHandler}>
     lock client’s account
</Button>

const LockUnlockAccountHandler = async () => {
  const status = await LockUnlockAccount(detailData?.userId, detailData?.blocked ? 'UNLOCK' : 'LOCK');
  console.log(status)
  if(status){
    setDetailData({
      ...detailData,
      blocked: !detailData.blocked
    })
  }
}
```

Status value is undefined in above function which should be true or false from below function.

```
export async function LockUnlockAccount(clientID, dataVal) {
  
  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: endpoint.lockAccount + clientID + "/status"  + endpoint.key,
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data : qs.stringify({
      'status': dataVal 
    })
  };
  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      if (response.status === 200) {
        toast('succès');
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast('error');
      return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: `axios(config)` -> `return axios(config)` or just `await` the result and return from the function itself. You've marked the function as async but don't use `await` anywhere in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `LockUnlockAccount`

You need to do

```
return axios(config).then(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to returned the response from axios, which is what will be returned by the wrapping function. just add return in front of axios call.
below is your updated code

```
export async function LockUnlockAccount(clientID, dataVal) {
  
  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: endpoint.lockAccount + clientID + "/status"  + endpoint.key,
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data : qs.stringify({
      'status': dataVal 
    })
  };
  return axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      if (response.status === 200) {
        toast('succès');
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast('error');
      return false;
    });
}
```